# Is there any way to remove the hash in WordPress databases?

Tags: wordpress, hash, md5

All of the passwords in WordPress databases are hashed. I'm running 20+ blogs with me as the only user. I often forget my password and have to reset it. Is there any way to remove the hash?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use a password manager, or the same password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is for [security reason](http://phpsec.org/articles/2005/password-hashing.html) that password should be hashed before saving to database and not recommended to store plain password in the database. the hashing is done in MD5 and it is extremly diffcult to reverse it even we apply filters.